# Show Calendar event on single line with Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When you create a Calendar appointment with Outlook 2013, that has a long subject line, it is displayed on multiple lines on the calendar, like this:
[image]

However, in previous version of Outlook, it would only show the first line of the subject like this:
[image]

I have a user that is wondering if it is possible to change Outlook 2013 to only display a single line, like previous versions of outlook did.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to View and then select Month.

You are probably selecting a set of days (let's say, about 14 days), which gives more room for text. For instance, if you select "week" or "work week", you are going to see the text in several lines if the appointment takes more than half an hour
If you select 21 days or more, every entry will be single line.

I hope it help's you...

Comment: Sorry, no. "Month" is the selected view in both examples, showing more that 21 days...

Answer (score 0):

On the View ribbon, click View Settings, then Other Settings in the dialog box, then set the Time Scale to be 60 minutes. That solved it for me, that setting had switched to be 30 minutes which changed the way the events displayed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, no. I tried changing the Time Scal to 60 minutes and it is still showing multiple lines